# Trying To Install Ember CLI Results In Error

Tags: ember-cli

Running a simple npm install -g ember-cli seems to throw an error related to a missing package:

Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@cnakazawa%2fwatch - Not found

Anyone see this error?

Comment: You can see on https://status.npmjs.org. Something wrong with npm.